# Amending NSAttributedString by comparison to new String retaining attributes?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsstring, nsattributedstring

Not sure the title is great, but here's the problem...

I am developing an app from a huge bunch of data which the user cannot change but can add things to like comments, notes, bookmarks etc...

I am considering using `NSAttributedString` to allow the user to add highlights to passages of text that are all `NSStrings` originally.

The problem I have is that the underlying data may change.  Sometimes because of human error (mistyping etc...) and other times because the data is simply updated.  Often this will be nothing more than correcting a word or two or adding/deleting a sentence to the original `NSString`.

What I am trying to avoid is replacing the string with the new string and losing the attributes or having them appear in the wrong place.

What I would like to do is find the differences between the new `NSString` and the old `NSString` and insert/delete the changes as appropriate without losing any of the existing attributes the user may have added.

For example I may have a `NSAttributedString` like this:

> The awl states that there are 5 days to respond.  In extreme cases this maybe reduced.

The user may have highlighted the first sentence or just the number 5.

I now need to amend this to:

> The law states that there are 5 days to respond.  In extreme cases this maybe reduced.

or:

> The article states that there are 5 days to respond.  In extreme cases this maybe reduced.

and maybe later to:

> The law states that there will be a period of 7 days to respond under normal circumstances.  In extreme cases this may be reduced.  It is rare that a longer period would be allowed.

...whilst at the same time retaining the gist of the formatting.  i.e. Keeping the entire sentence highlighted, or just keeping the number formatted.

I guess what I need is:

1. A way to determine the least possible number of edits required to
   arrive at the new string and
2. To perform these edits while interpreting and maintaining/extending the original attributes of the `NSAttributedString` as required.

I can achieve 2. by explicitly inserting/replacing/deleting the characters in the string for a specified example.

But I am at a loss on how to get the info for 1. i.e determine which characters need to be inserted/deleted/replaced for any pair of OLD & NEW strings.

I hope this makes sense and that there is a simple 'comparison' method I have overlooked which can do this.

Any assistance greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**:
The more I think about this the less likely it seems it will be possible...  The current method of highlighting the entire string or nothing looks like it will have to do.  Either that or store the edits as actual 'strings to delete', 'strings to replace' or 'strings to insert'.

I'm still open to possibilities though so will leave the question up in case anyone has a solution.

Comment: Not sure if I understand all the consequences, but I understand `NSMutableAttributedString` holds a string and a dictionary of attributes applied over a range. It also provides methods for inserting, deleting and replacing attributedStrings, means the inserted or replaced string also has its attributes. They key for you would be to decide which attributes will be applied for inserted strings, either existing attributes on the left or right of the insert point, or none. `NSMutableAttributedString` takes care of shifting of the attributes range when the string changes, you get this free.

Comment: @MartinKoles thanks for the answer.  Yes, I know how to deal with the Attributes of the string and Inserting/Deleting/Replacing characters.  As I say I can do this for specific examples without any problems.  What I am trying to figure out is if it possible to take `NSString* A` and `NSString* B` and determine precisely what changes need to be made to change A into B.